# Angular view not updated following changes to OnPush Component created through ViewContainerRef

Tags: angular

Using Angular 4.3 and the following [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/KmVjhVqMwa6yJIortf5u?p=preview).

Please consider the following components:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <button type="button" (click)="toggle()">Toggle</button>
      <div #anchor></div>
    </div>
  `,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class App {
  @ViewChild('anchor', {read: ViewContainerRef}) anchor: ViewContainerRef;
  dynamicRef: ComponentRef;
  value = true;

  constructor(private cfr: ComponentFactoryResolver, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    let factory = this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(Dynamic);
    this.dynamicRef = this.anchor.createComponent(factory);
    this.dynamicRef.instance.value = this.value;
    this.dynamicRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }

  toggle(): void {
    this.value = !this.value;
    this.dynamicRef.instance.value = this.value;
    this.dynamicRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }
}

@Component({
  template: `Value: {{value}}`,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class Dynamic {
  @Input() value = true;
}
```

The `App` component creates the `Dynamic` component using the standard `ComponentFactoryResolver` + `ViewContainerRef` strategy. Both components have an `OnPush` change detection strategy. When the `App.toggle()` method is called, it toggles `App.value`, propagates this new value to `Dynamic.value` and forces a change detection run on the dynamic component's change detector.  I expect the correct value to be displayed by the dynamic component's template, but it actually never changes.  Switching both components to the `Default` change detection strategy provides the expected behaviour.

Why isn't the dynamic component template re-rendered properly and how can this be fixed?

Comment: Probably unrelated: class App is missing AfterViewInit implementation

Comment: Not sure what you mean, I do see App.ngAfterViewInit() {...} in both the Plunkr and this post?

Comment: export class App implements AfterViewInit https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit#how-to-use

Comment: Yes the lifecycle interface hasn't been added to the class declaration.  I think it's unrelated to this issue though.

Comment: That's what I said :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Every dynamically created component has a host view. So you have the following hierarchy:

```
AppComponentView
   DynamicComponentHostView
       DynamicComponentView
```

When you do:

```
this.dynamicRef.changeDetectorRef
```

you get `changeDetectorRef` of the `DynamicComponentHostView`. And when you run `detectChanges` you run change detection for the `DynamicComponentHostView`, not `DynamicComponentView`.

Then, if you set `OnPush` strategy the parent component updates bindings of the child component and decides whether to run change detection on the child component or not. However, it's important, that the input bindings be defined during compilation in the template. Which is not the case with dynamic components. So you have to trigger change detection manually on this component if you want to use OnPush. To do that, you need to get the change detector of the `DynamicComponentView`. You can do it like this:

```
export class Dynamic {
  @Input() value = true;

  constructor(public cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {

  }
```

And then trigger change detection like this:

```
this.dynamicRef.instance.cd.detectChanges();
```

[Here is the plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/soTlKRoWVUhTGGVvERk5?p=preview).

For more information about change detection read [Everything you need to know about change detection in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f).

Comment: @Spiff, you're welcome. I write a lot about this kind of stuff in [angularindepth.com](https://blog.angularindepth.com/). You might want to follow the publication. Good luck

Comment: Absolutely helpful

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! Is it possible to get the ChangeDetectorRef of the dynamically created component without declaring it in the constructor? Like getting it from the list of injectable services of a component?

Comment: @mvermand, I don't think so